# opnsense disable anti flood

Tags: firewall, flooding

I've just installed OPNSense; it's working ok, I can have traffic in/out, but when trying to use a sustained stream such as rtmp, it stops after a few kB. If I disable the firewall, the stream goes on, so I guess there is some kind of flood prevention enabled.
Is there a way to disable it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from the Opnsense forum: I just have to disable stateful inspection.

https://forum.opnsense.org/index.php?topic=6267.msg26509#msg26509